# Keycloak with .NET WASM and .NET API

Tags: c#, authentication, keycloak, webassembly, .net-7.0

I have `Keycloak` running in a docker container, a `.NET 7` WASM PWA project (standalone, client only, no server) and a `.NET 7` API server.

I can authenticate against `Keycloak` and show permissions with the WASM project and I can authenticate via `swagger` in the API server and then call `Authorize` Controller endpoints.

**But** I cannot transfer the `JWT` from the WASM project to the API.

I tried and followed thies great tutorial: https://nikiforovall.github.io/blazor/dotnet/2022/12/08/dotnet-keycloak-blazorwasm-auth.html and even downloaded the source code. Everything works fine, but it is an WASM server project, not a standalone project with API server like I have.

I can recreate the problem with an MWE, so I can make sure none of my boiler plate code is creating the issue. Looking at a `Fiddler` log, I could see that the `JWT` is not transferred:
[image]
I would expect an `authorize: Bearer`, but it is missing.

On the WASM client I added

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(httpClientName, client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(httpClientName));
```

This *should* append the token to outgoing messages, like documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but it doesn't.

**Edit:** I am almost certain, that the reason the JWT is not automatically added to outgoing messages is because of *Access tokens are only added when the request URI is within the app's base URI.*

How can I change the `BaseUri` in `Blazor WASM` application to my `Web API`? Setting the `BaseUri` in the `HttpClient` is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to implement and use `CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-authorizationmessagehandler-class) with the URI to the `Web API`:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, 
        NavigationManager navigation)
        : base(provider, navigation)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(authorizedUrls: new[] { webApiUri });
    }
}
```